# Bootstrap Validator submit form

Tags: jquery, forms, bootstrapvalidator

I am using bootstrapValidator.min.js 0.5.3 at this moment to validate a form :
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.bootstrapvalidator/0.5.3/js/bootstrapValidator.min.js

Now this works fine for a contact form where i bind a send mail event to.

But now i want to use it for a form where he needs to validate the form , send the mail and submit the form so i can $_POST get the fields to write it to mysql.

Note also that i have a foreach loop to make more forms when added more objects. (form is used to apply for a job , jobs can be added in the backend.)

**The code :**

I will not post the form html and PHP because i know they work. Unless asked. Its a really long form and i don't want to clutter this with offtopic code.

Validator :

```
 jQuery('.form-job').each(function (i, obj) {
        jQuery(this).bootstrapValidator({
            fields: {
                firstname: {
                    validators: {
                        stringLength: {
                            min: 2,
                            message: 'Gelieve 2 of meer letters in te vullen.'
                        },
                        notEmpty: {
                            message: 'Vul aub uw naam in.'
                        }
                    }
                },
                lastname: {
                    validators: {
                        stringLength: {
                            min: 2,
                            message: 'Gelieve 2 of meer letters in te vullen.'
                        },
                        notEmpty: {
                            message: 'Vul aub uw achternaam in.'
                        }
                    }
                },
                street: {
                    validators: {
                        stringLength: {
                            min: 5,
                            message: 'Gelieve 5 of meer letters in te vullen.'
                        },
                        notEmpty: {
                            message: 'Vul aub uw straat in.'
                        }
                    }
                },
                housenumber: {
                    validators: {
                        stringLength: {
                            max: 8,
                            message: 'Vul aub een geldige huisnummer in.'
                        },
                        notEmpty: {
                            message: 'Vul aub uw huisnummer in.'
                        },
                    }
                },
                postal: {
                    validators: {
                        stringLength: {
                            min: 4,
                            max: 8,
                            message: 'Vul aub een geldige postcode in.'
                        },
                        notEmpty: {
                            message: 'Vul aub uw postcode in.'
                        },
                    }
                },
                city: {
                    validators: {
                        stringLength: {
                            min: 2,
                            message: 'Gelieve 2 of meer letters in te vullen.'
                        },
                        notEmpty: {
                            message: 'Vul aub uw stad in.'
                        }
                    }
                },
                country: {
                    validators: {
                        stringLength: {
                            min: 2,
                            message: 'Gelieve 2 of meer letters in te vullen.'
                        },
                        notEmpty: {
                            message: 'Vul aub uw land in.'
                        }
                    }
                },
                email: {
                    validators: {
                        notEmpty: {
                            message: 'Vul aub uw e-mailadres in.'
                        },
                        emailAddress: {
                            message: 'Vul aub een geldig e-mailadres in.'
                        }
                    }
                },
                telephone: {
                    validators: {
                        numeric: {
                            message: 'Gelieve alleen nummers te gebruiken.',
                        },
                        stringLength: {
                            min: 9,
                            message: 'Gelieve 9 of meer cijfers in te vullen.'
                        },
                        notEmpty: {
                            message: 'Vul aub een geldig telefoonnummer in.'
                        }
                    }
                },
                motivation: {
                    validators: {
                        stringLength: {
                            min: 10,
                            max: 550,
                            message: 'Vul aub minstens meer dan 10 letters in en minder dan 550.'
                        },
                        notEmpty: {
                            message: 'Vul aub uw vraag in.'
                        }
                    }
                },
                cvurl: {
                    validators: {
                        file: {
                            extension: 'doc,docx,pdf,txt',
                            type: 'application/pdf,application/msword,application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document,application/txt',
                            maxSize: 5 * 1024 * 1024,   // 5 MB
                            message: 'Het geselecteerd bestand is niet geldig. Dit moet een .doc, .docx, .pdf of een .txt zijn en max 5 MB groot.'
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        })
            .on('success.form.bv', function (e) {
                jQuery("#button").css('color', 'green');
                jQuery("#button").css('border', '2px solid green');
                jQuery(".alert-success").css('display', 'block');
                jQuery("#button").html('Verstuurd');
                jQuery(this).data('bootstrapValidator').resetForm();

                // Prevent form submission
                e.preventDefault();

                // Get the form instance
                var form = jQuery(e.target);

                // Get the BootstrapValidator instance
                var bv = form.data('bootstrapValidator');

                jQuery.post(my_ajax_object.ajax_url, form.serialize());

            });
    });
```

Don't mind the dutch please. Anything dutch shouldn't matter to the problem as it is just text that is displayed.

Also i know it says :

```
                // Prevent form submission
            e.preventDefault();
```

But when i delete it or comment it out nothing changes.

**So i need it to validate , send the mail (which works) and submit.**

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So i have made this work.

The problem was that i was trying to get the mail send by ajax trough JS trough the BootstrapValidator.

So what i ended up with was deleting the part that defined anything in the JS and i have this left:

```
jQuery('.form-job').each(function (i, obj) {
        jQuery(this).bootstrapValidator({
            fields: {
                firstname: {
                    validators: {
                        stringLength: {
                            min: 2,
                            message: 'Gelieve 2 of meer letters in te vullen.'
                        },
                        notEmpty: {
                            message: 'Vul aub uw naam in.'
                        }
                    }
                },
                lastname: {
                    validators: {
                        stringLength: {
                            min: 2,
                            message: 'Gelieve 2 of meer letters in te vullen.'
                        },
                        notEmpty: {
                            message: 'Vul aub uw achternaam in.'
                        }
                    }
                },
                street: {
                    validators: {
                        stringLength: {
                            min: 5,
                            message: 'Gelieve 5 of meer letters in te vullen.'
                        },
                        notEmpty: {
                            message: 'Vul aub uw straat in.'
                        }
                    }
                },
                housenumber: {
                    validators: {
                        stringLength: {
                            max: 8,
                            message: 'Vul aub een geldige huisnummer in.'
                        },
                        notEmpty: {
                            message: 'Vul aub uw huisnummer in.'
                        },
                    }
                },
                postal: {
                    validators: {
                        stringLength: {
                            min: 4,
                            max: 8,
                            message: 'Vul aub een geldige postcode in.'
                        },
                        notEmpty: {
                            message: 'Vul aub uw postcode in.'
                        },
                    }
                },
                city: {
                    validators: {
                        stringLength: {
                            min: 2,
                            message: 'Gelieve 2 of meer letters in te vullen.'
                        },
                        notEmpty: {
                            message: 'Vul aub uw stad in.'
                        }
                    }
                },
                country: {
                    validators: {
                        stringLength: {
                            min: 2,
                            message: 'Gelieve 2 of meer letters in te vullen.'
                        },
                        notEmpty: {
                            message: 'Vul aub uw land in.'
                        }
                    }
                },
                email: {
                    validators: {
                        notEmpty: {
                            message: 'Vul aub uw e-mailadres in.'
                        },
                        emailAddress: {
                            message: 'Vul aub een geldig e-mailadres in.'
                        }
                    }
                },
                telephone: {
                    validators: {
                        numeric: {
                            message: 'Gelieve alleen nummers te gebruiken.',
                        },
                        stringLength: {
                            min: 9,
                            message: 'Gelieve 9 of meer cijfers in te vullen.'
                        },
                        notEmpty: {
                            message: 'Vul aub een geldig telefoonnummer in.'
                        }
                    }
                },
                motivation: {
                    validators: {
                        stringLength: {
                            min: 10,
                            max: 550,
                            message: 'Vul aub minstens meer dan 10 letters in en minder dan 550.'
                        },
                        notEmpty: {
                            message: 'Vul aub uw vraag in.'
                        }
                    }
                },
                cvurl: {
                    validators: {
                        file: {
                            extension: 'doc,docx,pdf,txt',
                            type: 'application/pdf,application/msword,application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document,application/txt',
                            maxSize: 5 * 1024 * 1024,   // 5 MB
                            message: 'Het geselecteerd bestand is niet geldig. Dit moet een .doc, .docx, .pdf of een .txt zijn en max 5 MB groot.'
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        })
    });
```

And then i just call a function after the submit button with an

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])
```

(this is an example , never use submit as name of your submit button).

The function that i call sends a mail then and uses a query for the database part